# JS loads only first value from list of values

Tags: javascript, html, forms, cart

I am having trouble with this JS. It only loads the first value to the cart (8 x 13 Enlightenment - Open Edition Reproduction:60.00) with every selection from the drop down. Any suggestions? Thanks

HTML

```
<div><form action="https://sampleurl.com" method="post" name="myForm">
        <input type="Hidden" name="return" value="https://sampleurl.com">
    <input type="Hidden" name="userid" value="samplesuerid">
    <input type="Hidden" name="thumb" value="sample.jpg">
        <input type="Hidden" name="productpr" value="">
                        
                        
<select onchange="switchImage();" class="dropdown" name="switch">
        <option value="0">Select Size</option>
        <option value="1">8 x 13 paper - $60</option> 
        <option value="2">12 x 20 paper - $125</option> 
        <option value="3">18 x 30 paper - $225</option>
 </select>
```

JS

```
var imageList = Array();
for (var i = 1; i <= 7; i++) {
  imageList[i] = new Image(500, 500);
  imageList[i].src = "https://sampleurl.com/images/" + i + ".jpg";
}

function switchImage() {
  var selectedImage = document.myForm.switch.options[document.myForm.switch.selectedIndex].value;
  document.myImage.src = imageList[selectedImage].src;
}

if (i = 1) {
  document.querySelector('input[name="productpr"]').value = "8 x 13 Enlightenment - Open Edition Reproduction:60.00";
} else if (i = 2) {
  document.querySelector('input[name="productpr"]').value = "12 x 20 Enlightenment - Limited Edition Reproduction:125.00";
} else if (i = 3) {
  document.querySelector('input[name="productpr"]').value = "18 x 30 Enlightenment - Limited Edition Reproduction:225.00";
}
```

Comment: Make sure you use the right operators. `=` is for assignment, `===` is for comparison.

Comment: The `if` statement is not inside the `for` loop. So the value of `i` will always be `8` when you get there.

Comment: Array indexes start at 0, not 1.

Comment: I get a syntax Error when I place the if inside the for loop. Says, Price not set when I add to cart.